# How do i Import this data in to SQL table?

Tags: mysql

how do i import the following data into SQL table?? (data comes from a text file)

```
RECORD
#input_id 1443169798x012_0014076
#output_id 
#input_type uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord
#output_type uMTSGSMPLMNCallDataRecord
#addkey 
#source_id TEST
#filename TEST_20150923190000_008205.DMP
B roamingCallForwarding
F callPosition 2
F chargeableDuration 000000
F dateForStartOfCharge 0f0917
F exchangeIdentity MSSRST2 /13A/01
F interruptionTime 000000
F recordSequenceNumber 6814a9
F tariffClass 0001
F tariffSwitchInd 0
F timeForStartOfCharge 123b15
F timeForStopOfCharge 123b15
F outputType 4
F switchIdentity 00c8
F bladeID 00
F mobileSubscriberNumberForHLRInterrogation 14824044931
F calledPartyNumber 14824044931
F mobileStationRoamingNumber 1468085824044931
F mSCIdentification 1166853696501
F calledSubscriberIMSI 068085
F globalCallReference 040284080902c800035557d9
F callingPartyNumber 1166881633602
.
.
```

i would like to have the data into columns. for eaxmple:

```
callPosition| chargeableDuration| dateForStartOfCharge
           2|             000000|               0f0917
```

the database i am using in MySQL. thanks

Comment: More details required; where does the data come from, is it a file? And if so, what sort of file? What does the target table look like? Is the target table already present?

Comment: data comes from a text file.  i don't have a target table yet but the column header should look like roamingCallForwarding | callPosition | chargeableDuration

Comment: If you don't want any programming involved then you can convert your data into SQL statements and import it into your DB via Command line or MySQL Admin pages etc

Comment: Best way i think would be to write some kind of parser that would in a loop,  in first iteration create table and then, just insert data.